# C# Remove duplicate logic

Tags: c#

I have a List like this,

```
COL1  COL2  COL3
    ----  ----  -----
    AA    AB    Some text  
    AA    AC    Some text
    AA    AB    Some text
    AB    AB    Some text
    AB    AC    Some text
    AA    AC    Some text
```

I am looking for a fast and efficient logic in C# (perhaps in + LINQ) to remove duplicates in these two columns (COL1 , COL2 ) (Same like remove duplicates in Excel)

End result should be

```
AA  AB Some text
AA  AC Some text
AB  AB Some text
AB  AC Some text
```

Please advice

Comment: You need to show how the columns are stored in memory in terms of objects. Chances are you will be using the LINQ Distinct extension.

Comment: What data structure is this data in? Two lists? If so, the `.Distinct()` extension in LINQ will be your method.

Comment: How can i .Distinct()  only for COL1, COL2 ?

Comment: You can't distinct for only col1 and col2 unless you want to discard col3 altogether. What should go in col3 if the text was different each time?

Comment: By implementing your own comparer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Comment: A distinct for just Col1 and Col2 if you also want Col3 is actually a grouping rather than a distinct query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use suggestion given by @Zerkms. For example, assuming your object type is MyRow:

```
public class MyRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyRow>
{
   public override bool Equals(MyRow r1, MyRow r2)
   {
      // adjust the logic as per your need e.g. case-insensitive etc
      return r1.Col1 == r2.Col1 && r1.Col2 == r2.Col2;
   }

   public override int GetHashCode(MyRow r)
   {
      // TODO: add null check etc
      return r.Col1.GetHashCode() ^ r.Col2.GetHashCode()
   }
}

IEnumerable<MyRow> myList = ...;
...
myList.Distinct(new MyRowComparer());
```

Comment: While this is fine for the question the OP asked (you didn't have a lot of choices), You might want to caution users against using mutable properties in your hashcode. This [Eric Lippert article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx?PageIndex=2) goes into detail on this

Comment: @Conrad, thanks for putting that disclaimer! Although, it may not apply in this context. As long as those object does not mutate in the operation where MyRowComparer instance is used, its OK to use such implementation. I believe that in most of the use cases, this will be true (but of course, you never know).

Answer (score 1):

This i the solution by Distinct

```
var query = (from record in MyList select record).Distinct();
```

Comment: `(from record in MyList select record)` === `MyList`

Comment: Depending on where he is getting the data, the default comparer might check all columns.  He only cares about duplicates in the first two columns.

Comment: You can use group by to do it.